# Add a hyperlink to a body of text

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink, html-email

The following code to sends an email when a change is made to a workbook.

I would like to change the file location in the body of the text so that it is a hyperlink.

I tried `click<a href=""`

I removed email addresses for data protection.

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim Outlook As Object, EMail As Object
    
    Set Outlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    
    Set EMail = Outlook.CreateItem(0)
    
    With EMail
        .To = " "
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Billing Block Sheet"
        .Body = "Hi." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "A change has been made to the billing block spreadsheet." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "P:\Admin\Wilson Pre pack (billing block).xlsm"
        .Display   'or use .Send to skip preview
    End With
    
    Set EMail = Nothing
    
    Set Outlook = Nothing
End Sub
    
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    
End Sub
```

Comment: It just keeps throwing syntax errors at me

Comment: Could it be due to "& vbCrLf & vbCrLf &" that I am using to separate paragraphs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `.HTMLBody` instead of `.Body` and `<br>` instead of `vbCrLf` and you need to double up on the quote marks since you are building a string and you want the quotes included in the string.

Thy it like this:

```
.HTMLBody = "Hi.<br><br>A change has been made to the billing block spreadsheet.<br><br><a href=""P:\Admin\Wilson Pre pack (billing block).xlsm"">click here</a>"
```

Comment: do I need to add strBody to this as it now html?

Comment: Thank you, realised that I had tried changing the body format and did not remove it before trying the 2 quotes instead of 3 so was getting a run time error before I realised. Thank you so much … so sensitive to punctuation these things.